# example for rigorous two phase locking

Tags: database, locking

The image below shows an example of an S2PL transaction, can anyone convert this example to R2PL?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The differences between S2PL and R2PL is really only during the second phase, i.e. how they release locks.

For S2PL, the locks for a transaction must hold all its locks till it commits or aborts, while R2PL releases all locks only after commit or abort.

So, to convert it to R2PL, you just have to move the `unlock(A)` to after the `commit` point, and before `unlock(B)`.